# Django query on value of a ForeignKey field

Tags: django

I want to pick up all Runner records where the `main_contact.paid=True`.  I cannot workout the Django call.

Here are the models:

```
class Main_contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    tel = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Runner(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fee = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    main_contact = models.ForeignKey(Main_contact)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try traversing the relationship with:

```
Runner.objects.filter(main_contact__paid=True)
```

Comment: Too bloody easy - I was typing main_contact.paid!  Thank you

Comment: No worries! The syntax you were using is template syntax, it's easy to mix them up at first. So in a template, if you wanted to render the value of a Runner->Main_contact->paid you'd use `{{ runner_object.main_contact.paid }}`. So you were on the right track, just had them mixed up is all